# Find for which $\lambda$ the following system of equations has a solution

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

I want to determine for which $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ the following linear system over $\mathbb{R}$ has a solution:

\begin{cases}
x_1 + 2x_2 - 3x_3 = \lambda\\
3x_1 + 5x_2 - 3x_3 = 2\lambda\\
-3x_1-4x_2-3x_3=1
\end{cases}

I would like to understand how to solve this exercise. Here's the augmented matrix to make it a little easier to solve:

\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&-3&\lambda\\
3&5&-3&2\lambda\\
-3&-4&-3&1
\end{bmatrix}

I know that systems like these have a solution (one or infinite) if the rank of the coefficients matrix A matches the rank of the augmented matrix $A|b$. However, I don't know how I would go about evaluating the rank of $A|b$. Sure, I could try to calculate the determinant of all the submatrices of order 3 until I find that one has determinant $\neq 0$ but that would take a while.

Also, I've tried to reduce the matrix in row-echelon form but I can't see how to go from there.

\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&-3&\lambda\\
0&-1&0&-\lambda\\
0&1&-6&3\lambda
\end{bmatrix}

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In trying to reduce the augmented matrix to the reduced row-echelon form, we have

$$
\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&2&-3&\lambda\\
3&5&-3&2\lambda\\
-3&-4&-3&1
\end{array}\right)&\equiv
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&2&-3&\lambda\\
0&-1&6&-\lambda\\
0&2&-12&3\lambda+1
\end{array}\right)\tag{1}\\
&\equiv
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&0&9&-\lambda\\
0&-1&6&-\lambda\\
0&0&0&\lambda+1
\end{array}\right)\tag{2}
\end{align*}
$$
From the last augmented matrix, we see that we need to have $\lambda+1=0$ 
otherwise the system would be inconsistent. So to have solution, we need $\lambda=-1$.

The row operations that I did in 1 from top to bottom rows are
$R_1\longrightarrow R_1$, $R_2\longrightarrow -3R_1+R_2$, and $R_3\longrightarrow 3R_1+R_3$, respectively.

The row operations that I did in 2 from top to bottom rows are 
$R_1\longrightarrow2R_2+R_1$, $R_2\longrightarrow R_2$, and $R_3\longrightarrow2R_2+R_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the determinant of the first matrix is zero. So the equations are not linearly independent.

It is not hard to see that taking 4 times 2nd + 2 times 3rd minus 6 times 1st eliminates the lhs irrespective of the values of the $x_i$, and gives $\lambda=-1$.

So there are multiple solutions for $\lambda=-1$ and no solutions otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. So if the determinant of the first matrix wasn’t zero, then we’d have full rank and therefore a solution correct?

Comment: Call the oriiginal matrix $A$. Then the original equation can be written as $Av=c$, where $v$ is the column vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $c$ is the column vector $(\lambda,2\lambda,1)$. If $\det A\ne0$, then $A$ has an inverse $A^{-1}$, so multiplying both sides by $A^{-1}$ we get $v=Ac$ which gives a solution (in fact the unique solution) irrespective of the value of $\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you. I love how math makes sense.